# How do I work with PDT and WAMP

Tags: php, eclipse, wamp, wampserver

I have installed PDT for Eclipse and WAMP server. I want to know how do i start writing code in PHP now? What should I do so that WAMP gets all my PHP files? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WAMP works by reading the www directory, usually under C:\wamp\www.  If you place your own index.php file there you will see it in the browser when you start WAMP and go to http://localhost

In terms of PDT for Eclipse you can simply create your project at C:\wamp\www.  Now all your code will exist in the www directory thus giving WAMP access to your project code and allowing you to test your code.